# how to get serialized post meta

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta, wpdb, phpmyadmin

I have posts that have video content and these videos stored in database like this (serialized)  `a:1:{s:9:"video_url";s:0:"";}` 
This serialized data have post video urls but can not get this data. I used `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_field', TRUE); ?>`
But this get_post_meta display output "array" instead of video urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) with the 3rd parameter set to `true` will return a single item with the key specified in the 2nd parameter (`_custom_field` in your code). If this item is an array, it'll return as the array. In your case, it appears that the data is:

```
array(
    'video_url' => '',
)
```

...which is why, when you try to `echo` it, it's printing `Array` to the screen.

I'd suggest something more like this:

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_field', TRUE);
echo $meta['video_url'];
?>
```

...or, if you're expecting multiple `video_url`s, you could do this:

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_field');
foreach ( $meta as $item ) {
    echo $item['video_url'];
}
?>
```

(Note that it also appears that, in the metadata you've posted, there's an empty value for the actual `video_url`, but I can't say what might have caused *that*.)

Comment: thank you very much for your attention.  It is singe url.  your code return empty value. coud it be that serialzed data get file url by file id from media library?

Comment: The serialized data in your question shows an empty value. I can't guess what might be in your media gallery.